# Обновление изображения на окне тормозит работу программы

Tags: c#, wpf

Я использую Emge CV библиотеку для захвата видео с вебкамеры. Установленной мной fps равен 20. Т.е. 20 раз в секунды вызывается обработчик события готовности нового фрейма и он должен быть отрисован на окне.

```
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => {
            Img.Source = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(videoCapture.QueryFrame().Bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }));
```

К сожалению, это очень сильно грузит окно, вследствие чего, оно часто виснет. Я пробовал разные приоритеты диспатчера, и хуже всех, что логично, оказался `Normal`.

Как разгрузить окно?

---

У меня есть мыслишка. Но она состоит в отказе от использования обработчика.
Использовать `DispatcherTimer` и в обработчике `Tick` события запускать `Task`, в котором запускать в отдельном потоке диспетчера UI поток с `Normal` приоритетом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть, поможет выгрузка работы с камерой в фоновый поток:

```
// в UI-потоке
Img.Source = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var bmp = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            videoCapture.QueryFrame().Bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        bmp.Freeze(); // открепляем от потока
        return bmp;
    });
```

Если обработчик вызывается не в UI-потоке, можно «обратить» логику:

```
var bmp = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    videoCapture.QueryFrame().Bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
    IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
bmp.Freeze(); // открепляем от потока
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Img.Source = bmp);
```

---

Если вы используете Rx Extensions, можно поменять частоту на нужную «на лету»:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern(camera, nameof(NewImageArrived))
          .Select(args => CreateBitmap())
          .Sample(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0/8)) // 8 раз в секунду
          .DistinctUntilChanged()
          .ObserveOnDispatcher()
          .Subscribe(bmp => Imh.Source = bmp)
```

где функция `CreateBitmap` определена как

```
var bmp = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    videoCapture.QueryFrame().Bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
    IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
    BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
bmp.Freeze(); // открепляем от потока
return bmp;
```

Comment: Спасибо. А что вы скажете о предложенном мною методе?

Comment: Можно вопрос не по теме? Просто думаю, может вы знаете, чтобы отдельный вопрос не создавать... Как задать у камеры какую-либо настройку через WinApi? Например, фокус, наклон, поворот, диафрагма и т.д. Через DeviceIOControl предварительно открыв handle устройства? А по каким ключевым словам гуглить доступные настройки для камеры?

Comment: @D.Stark: Я не вполне понял, что означает «запускать в отдельном потоке диспетчера UI поток с Normal приоритетом», если честно. Вы имеете в виду _второй_ UI-поток?

Comment: @D.Stark: А разве у камеры нету своего API? Я работал с камерой через API, а что предоставляет обычная веб-камера, я, к сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: Я имею ввиду так: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => { ... }));`.

Comment: По поводу API я даже и не слышал. Вы имеете ввиду камеру подключенную через USB или как? И что, API разный у каждой модели камеры?

Comment: @D.Stark: Ну, это выполняет Action в UI-потоке, а мы ж хотим его разгрузить. Если это запускать из UI-потока, то выполнено будет всё равно в UI-потоке, просто позже.

Comment: @D.Stark: Мне приходилось работать с какой-то достаточно дорогой специализированной камерой, и у неё был свой API. С «обыкновенными» камерами работать не приходилось.

Comment: Дак я в отдельной задаче запускаю)

Comment: А думаете эта камера поддерживает обычное взаимодействие? Как с вебкамерами. Должна.

Comment: Вот как это выглядит: https://pastebin.com/jSND74eT. Вообще не тормозит.

Comment: @D.Stark: Ну, отдельная-не отдельная, это не так важно для пользователя. Для пользователя важно, висит или не висит UI-поток. Если висит — приложение с точки зрения пользователя лагает. А то, отдельный это таск или нет, пользователь не видит, на его восприятие это не влияет.

Comment: А зачем `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(`? Вы сначала отправляете код из UI-потока на пул, а оттуда отправляете снова в UI.

Comment: Странно, но это идеально всё разгружает.

Comment: @D.Stark: А если исключить `Task.Run()`? Или использовать вместо `DispatcherTimer` другой таймер, который не возвращает в UI-поток?

Comment: Извините, не могли бы помочь с [таким вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/855991/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-windows/856454#856454)?