# Вопросы тестирования программного обеспечения в Windows

Tags: .net, windows, тестирование

Меня интересует вопрос тестирования программного обеспечения, когда продукт уже создан, но ещё не протестирован (речь пойдёт о продуктах использующих .NET Framework).

Так, допустим я хочу, чтобы моё приложение работало на следующих ОС: Windows Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10.

Кстати, кроме прочего, используется DirectX Media Foundation.

---

Вопрос в следующем:

1. Имеется ли разница между тестированием на 32- и на 64-разрядной версии ОС?
2. Если я тестирую продукт под, например, Windows 7, должен ли тестировать его так же с установленным Service Pack?
3. Где я смогу найти ISO образы нужных версий ОС с целью тестирования (виртуализация в VMware)?

Answer (score 1):

> Имеется ли разница между тестированием на 32- и на 64-разрядной версии
>   ОС?

Разница очень небольшая. Она есть для С++ (хотя проблемы возникают очень редко), а вот для шарпа так даже сходу и не придумаю сценарий, чтобы были проблемы. В общем, в вашем случае можно, наверное, с этим не заморачиваться.

> Если я тестирую продукт под, например, Windows 7, должен ли
>   тестировать его так же с установленным Service Pack?

С сервис паком определенно нет смысла тратить время. Даже с каждой системой не нужно тестировать. Выберите 2-3 ключевые системы, скажем, наименьшую поддерживаемую вашей программой, актуальную, и желательно что-нибудь посередине. Например, WinXP-Win7-Win10.

В других системах достаточно просто проверить проблемные места - например, в Win8 отсутствует кнопка Пуск, для нее стоит сделать альтернативный доступ к программной группе. Один раз проверили, разобрались со специфическими нюансами, дальше в ней тестировать не обязательно.

> Где я смогу найти ISO образы нужных версий ОС с целью тестирования
>   (виртуализация в VMware)?

Только в MSDN, естественно. Ну или в некоторых некошерных местах, которые называть не будем.